# App data usage and storage information in Ionic 5 app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to fetch my app data usage and storage information in Ionic 5 app , How to do that ?

Comment: Do you mean disk space and data?

Comment: You can do something with SQLite.

Comment: i want to fetch how much data is being used by my ionic app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Diagnostic plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic) for getting device-related information.

In your particular case, to get the storage information (free space, filled space etc.), use `getExternalSdCardDetails()` method provided by plugin:

```
diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(details=>
{
  console.log('Details',details);
});
```

I haven't used App Data Usage information, but you can try [App Center Analytics](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-center-analytics) plugin and track the data usage. Read the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/cordova)

Comment: Diagonostic plugin only Checks whether device hardware features are enabled or available to the app, e.g. camera, GPS, wifi . Cant fetch app resource usage.

Comment: Also i dont think it can be done by App Center Analytics !

Comment: Storage information can be fetched with Diagnostic plugin. Network usage information however is not possible yet.

Comment: can i fetch how much local storage data is being used by my ionic app with it ?

Comment: This might help: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-check-the-size-of-local-storage-used-by-JavaScript/answer/Samuli-Hakoniemi